# MWAA use both wheel dependencies and PyPI dependencies

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I'm trying to use both a wheel dependency that I created and, additionally, use PyPi dependencies in MWAA.

I was basing the steps I did on this article:
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/mwaa-install-custom-packages

My requirements.txt file:

```
--find-links /usr/local/airflow/plugins/plugins
--no-index 

apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==4.0.2
apache-airflow-providers-mysql==4.0.0
awswrangler==2.19.0
sagemaker==2.140.1

/usr/local/airflow/plugins/plugins/example_wheel.whl
```

in the plugins dir I created a plugins.zip file with the wheel inside of it at it's root.

When running Airflow locally using this project: https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner
Both the PyPi dependencies are not recognized and the wheel dependency isn't recognized.

I see the following error in the UI if the awswrangler import is first in the code:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awswrangler'
```

and the same error for import a class defined in my wheel if that import comes first in the code.

If I keep only the PyPi imports in the requirements file and remove the --index and --find-links and the wheel import then at least these imports are not failing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the local runner, just put the files in the root of the plugins folder. MWAA will extract the content from the plugins.zip into that folder on start up

Comment: @SimonP I did put the plugins.zip file in the plugins folder, or did you mean other files?

Comment: The plugins.zip is for uploading to S3. The contents should be in the plugins folder

Comment: @SimonP very nice, this solved the issue locally! however, when uploading to actual AWS MWAA I still need to use the plugins.zip right?

Comment: I tested the contents of the plugins folder on AWS using the BashOperator, seems that the wheel file reaches /usr/local/airflow/plugins/plugins/example_wheel.whl.

Comment: Mwaa need the plugins folder zipped up. Correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, I can use both local wheels and PyPi dependencies. The following requirements file worked:

```
awswrangler==2.19.0
sagemaker==2.140.1
/usr/local/airflow/plugins/plugins/example_wheel.whl
```

Also, I tested the contents of the plugins folder and found that even though I place the wheel in the root of the zip file, the actual path of the wheel is as I wrote in the requirements above.